# Getting nested array from JSON using Jackson lib - Java

Tags: java, json, jackson

I've got a JSON like this:

```
    {
        "result": [
            {
                "reservation_id": 101,
                "euro_fee": 11.00,
                "hotel_id": 1
            },
            {
                "reservation_id": 102,
                "euro_fee": 12.00,
                "hotel_id": 2
            },
            {
                "reservation_id": 103,
                "euro_fee": 13.00,
                "hotel_id": 3
            }
        ],
        "meta": {
            "ruid": "0001="
        }
    }
```

and I'm trying to use Jackson (with Spring Boot) for parse and bind it. Here is my POJO's:

`Response.java`

```
    public class Response {

        private Result result;
        private Meta meta;

        public Response() {
        }

        public Result getResult() {
            return result;
        }

        public void setResult(Result result) {
            this.result = result;
        }

        public Meta getMeta() {
            return meta;
        }

        public void setMeta(Meta meta) {
            this.meta = meta;
        }
    }
```

`Meta.java`

```
    public class Meta {

        private String ruid;

        public Meta() {
        }

        public String getRuid() {
            return ruid;
        }

        public void setRuid(String ruid) {
            this.ruid = ruid;
        }
    }
```

`Result.java`

```
    public class Result {

        private Booking[] results;

        public Result() {
        }

        public Booking[] getResults() {
            return results;
        }

        public void setResult(Booking[] results) {
            this.results = results;
        }
    }
```

`Booking.java`

```
    public class Booking {


        private long reservation_id;

        private long hotel_id;

        private Double euro_fee;

        public Booking() {
        }

        public long getReservation_id() {
            return reservation_id;
        }

        public void setReservation_id(long reservation_id) {
            this.reservation_id = reservation_id;
        }

        public long getHotel_id() {
            return hotel_id;
        }

        public void setHotel_id(long hotel_id) {
            this.hotel_id = hotel_id;
        }


        public Double getEuro_fee() {
            return euro_fee;
        }

        public void setEuro_fee(Double euro_fee) {
            this.euro_fee = euro_fee;
        }
    }
```

I can get `ruid` from `meta` using:

```
        // getting JSON from REST
        String response = restTemplate.postForObject(resourceURL, httpEntity, String.class);

        // use jackson
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Response theResponse = mapper.readValue(response, Response.class);
        System.out.println("getRuid: " + theResponse.getMeta().getRuid());
```

but I can't get objects or single item from nested array. When I'm trying to get array of items I'm getting error:

`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of out of START_ARRAY token at [Source: (String)...`

I know this one should be easy, but I'm using Jackson for the first time and the problem might be somewhere in the deep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your Response class.

Try with this:

```
public class Response {

        private List<Booking> result;
        private Meta meta;
//getter setter
}
```

Comment: This helps me + I have excluded Result.java